# Rails app served under url segment behind ingress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes-ingress

I am looking for ideas on how to solve the following problem. I want to serve a rails app under an URL segment. The path to the rails app will be `https://example.com/app`. The landing page `https://example.com/` will be bunch of static HTML, CSS, and javascript.

This will be handled by ingress in a kubernetes cluster. Ingress is easy, I have all that configuration ready but the problem as I see it is how to handle redirects between `Location /app` and `Location /`.

Is there anything in rails that prevents this? Is it just a matter of trial and error?

Comment: Did you read this [Deploy to a subdirectory (relative URL root)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root)?

Comment: It's still not clear what are you asking about (how to create Rail app or how to use nginx ingress rewrite using defined [Captured groups](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target)